# I have a problem with making the program which returns the day of the year from the DD.MM.YYYY date dynamic

Tags: c, structure, dynamic-programming

**i tried to make the code dynamic, but i got an error. The main goal of the code to be dynamic( i read the literature about malloc and others but i don`t understand how to work with it correctly. I think that you will help me a little bit)**

```
char* dates_arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 6);
char* data_entered = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
if (dates_arr) {
    int counter = 3;
    char sep[] = ".";
    for (int c = 0; c < counter; c++) {
        gets(data_entered);
        char* pst = strtok(data_entered, sep);
        int i = 0;
        while (pst != NULL) {
            dates_arr[i] = atoi(pst);
            i++;
            pst = strtok(NULL, sep);
        }
        free(data_entered);
        int d_day = dates_arr[0];
        int d_month = dates_arr[1];
        int d_year = dates_arr[2];



        DATE res = Date(d_day, d_month, d_year);

        printf("\n\nThe day of year is: = %d", res.day);
        Gap();  
        printf("The string date is: %d of %s of %d", d_day, res.month, res.year);
        Gap();
        Beautify();
        free(dates_arr);
    }
}
else {
    printf("\n\n\nOOPS");
    return 0;
}
```

**THATS MY STRUCTURE AND FUNCTION that does all "Magic"**
*the result of the function will be the day regarding to the date;*

```
typedef struct {
int day;
char month[20];
int year;
} DATE;

DATE Date(int d, int m, int y) {                                                         
DATE date;
int day[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
//there are all the months
char month[12][20] = { .....months};
int d_day = d, d_month = m, d_year = y;

if (y % 4 == 0)
{
    if (y % 100 == 0)
    {
        if (y % 400 == 0)
            day[1] = 29;
    }
    else
        day[1] = 29;
}
if (d > 31) {
    while (d_month > 1) {
        d_day += day[d_month];
        d_month--;
    }
}


date.day = d_day;
strcpy(date.month, month[m-1]);
date.year = d_year;


return date;
```

}

**THATS WHICH WORKS, BUT I NEED DYNAMIC STRUCTURE OR ARRAY**

```
int date_arr[DATE_MAX];
char date_str[10];
gets(date_str);
char sep[] = ".";
char* pos = strtok(date_str, sep);

int i = 0;
while (pos != NULL) {
    date_arr[i] = atoi(pos);
    printf("%d ", date_arr[i]);
    i++;
    pos = strtok(NULL, sep);
}
int d_day = date_arr[0];
int d_month = date_arr[1];
int d_year = date_arr[2];

DATE res = Date(d_day, d_month, d_year);
printf("\n\nThe day of year is: = %d", res.day);
Gap();  
printf("The string date is: %d of %s of %d", d_day, res.month, res.year);
```

[what i entered first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCcvt.png) ,
[what i entered second and what error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljk0z.png)
On the second image is ERROR about **wntdll.pdb no loaded** and **.exe file caused the stop point**

Comment: `char* data_entered = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` will allocate ONE character. I think you want more, and don't forget the terminating null character of strings in C.

Comment: Please provide a [repro] and ask a specific question. It is not clear to me what specific question you need answered. Provide error messages in full, if you got one.

Comment: P.S don`t pay the attention to the details of Date funtion and its numbers, indexes)

Comment: regarding: `gets(date_str);`  The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the the C language several years ago.  Your compiler should have told you about this problem.

Comment: the posted code fails to allow for the fact that some countries write the date as MM/DD/YYYY  while others write it as: DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: NONE of the posted code compiles.  Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Do not post links to images.  Rather copy/paste the text directly into your question.